# Set SelectedItem in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, mvvm-light

I'm trying to set the SelectedItem in a ComboBox but without any success.

[image]

As you can see in the above screenshot it shows the first record from the Product list.

Here is the XAML :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
          Grid.Row="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          IsEditable="True"
          DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"
          Width="200"
          Height="30"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          Margin="10 0 0 20" />
```

The ViewModel :

```
public Product SelectedProduct
{
    get => _selectedProduct;
    set => Set(ref _selectedProduct, value);
}
```

And here I set the SelectedProduct :

```
private void OrderUserControl(Order order)
{
    ShowOrderUserControl = Visibility.Visible;

    Products = _productService.GetProducts();

    if (order == null)
    {
        Order = new Order();

        OrderUserControlTitle = "Nieuwe bestelling toevoegen";
    }
    else
    {
        Order = order;

        SelectedProduct = _productService.GetProductById(Order.ProductId);

        OrderUserControlTitle = "Bestelling aanpassen";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When the Product does not override the Equals method, you have to make sure that the object returned from SelectedProduct is an element of the Products collection.

Comment: Besides that, setting SelectedValuePath is pointless unless you also bind SelectedValue - instead of SelectedItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Product` class have an `Id` property,

You can get your `SelectedProduct` like this using linq instead of using your service again :

```
SelectedProduct = Products.Find(p => p.Id == Order.ProductId);
```

It ensures that your selected product is part of your `Products` list

Comment: Or (assuming that Order is a property with change notification) you bind `SelectedValue="{Binding Order.ProductId}"` instead of binding SelectedItem.

Comment: That did the trick, but why didn't it worked with my service? It returns also a Product object. @Clemens I will try that also.

Comment: See my comment on the question: "*make sure that the object returned from SelectedProduct is an element of the Products collection*" - i.e. not a *new* Product that is *not contained* in the collection.